# Intallation Error During install apk In Personal Mobile in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, installation, apk, failed-installation

My app was working Properly , I Just Com back after a few days and its need of work, I Disconnect all Firebase Related Work for Some Reason and now I'm running my App and its Showing This Error

**Pop-Up Message**
Session 'app': Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed

```
enter code here 
Installation did not succeed.
```

The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'E:\Uni\6thsemester\Ansari\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'

Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --dont-kill -S 13064814'

returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:

android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space

at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:506)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1380)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:276)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:116)

at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:29793)

at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:602)

at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:500)

at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3247)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5412)

at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:705)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space

at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:515)

at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:433)

at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:448)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:663)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:504)

... 10 more''
Retry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
```

Free up your phone memory. Your phone memory is full which cause your app is not install.